# How can I dockerize Nx React JS application

Tags: reactjs, docker, nrwl-nx

I have a react js application with nx build, it has one app and 15 libs. I tried everything to be able to dockerize but it didn't work.

DockerFile:

```
FROM node: 14.5.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "run", "start", "jsure-admin"]
```

docker-compose.base.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nx-app-base:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - DEV_PLATFORM=DOCKER
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - mono-node-modules:/app/node_modules
```

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  # React App
  app-1:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
      service: nx-app-base
    command: npm run jsure-admin:dev:docker
    ports:
      - 4200:4200

volumes:
  mono-node-modules: null
```

packege.json file:

```
{
  "name": "jsure",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nx serve",
    "jsure-admin":"jsure-admin",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test"
  },
...
```

Docker error:

```
2023-04-02 17:01:25 
2023-04-02 17:01:25 > jsure@0.0.0 start /app
2023-04-02 17:01:25 > nx serve "jsure-admin"
2023-04-02 17:01:25 
2023-04-02 17:01:26 
2023-04-02 17:01:26 > nx run jsure-admin:serve:development
2023-04-02 17:01:26 
2023-04-02 17:01:29 <i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
2023-04-02 17:01:29 
2023-04-02 17:01:29 >  NX  Web Development Server is listening at http://localhost:4200/
2023-04-02 17:01:29 
2023-04-02 17:01:29 <i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:4200/, http://127.0.0.1:4200/
2023-04-02 17:01:29 <i> [webpack-dev-server] 404s will fallback to '/index.html'
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e> [webpack-dev-middleware] HookWebpackError: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e>     at makeWebpackError (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:48:9)
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e>     at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3060:12
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e>     at eval (eval at create (/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:46:1)
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e>     at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:510:26
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e>     at /app/node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:708:13
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e> -- inner error --
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e> Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e>     at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:698:11)
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e>     at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:82:40)
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e>     at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:226:28)
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e>     at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:51:40)
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e>     at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:50:36)
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e> caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e> Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e>     at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:698:11)
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e>     at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:82:40)
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e>     at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:226:28)
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e>     at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:51:40)
2023-04-02 17:02:05 <e>     at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:50:36)
```

The project is already standing up without any errors, but when dockerized, the above error is received, and there is no problem when getting build for docker.

How can i do it?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text.

Comment: @possum fix it.